# Why is my miner offline in Slush's Pool?

Tags: cpu-mining

I just looked up how to mine bitcoin with my tablet and im using 2 apps: ARM Miner and Crypto miner, but my worker is considered offline when they are mining. Im getting KH so is that good? And should I use PikaArt or PikaArt.miner1 for my login into apps? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your tablet is too slow to even be assigned work by the pool.

Mining today is performed with [ASIC](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/12029/5406)s, specialized hardware that is literally a billion times more efficient than your tablet, clocking in at [terahashes per second](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/21498/5406).

Also see this more [comprehensive explanation by Dr.Haribo](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/38466/5406) why mining with Laptops isn't a good idea.